# How to show camera preview in Activity?

Tags: android, image, camera, capture, android-camera2

I came across many solutions on how to preview camera in Activity. But, they all use the deprecated `hardware.camera` for display.

How to do this using camera2? Any example for this available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your natural starting point would be the overview [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) and set of code samples [here](https://github.com/android/camera-samples). The Camera2Basic samples include code that you wouldn't need if you only want a preview (for example it also contains code necessary for saving a still image). However, I'd recommend starting there and then removing any code that you don't need for your particular purposes.